# Two different input fields in one line

Tags: html, css

I need to make the button and submit input type in 1 line and don't know how to do it.
I tried by changing display to inline but it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta  charset="utf-8">
        <title>Animated Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class ="box" action = "index.html" method="post">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <input type="username" name="" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Passeword">
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
            <input type="button" name="" value="Register">
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #34495e;   
}
.box{
    width: 300px;
    padding: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #191919;
    text-align: center;
}
.box h1{
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;

}
.box input[type = "username"],.box input[type = "password"]{
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #3498db;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    width: 200px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 24px;
    transition: 0.25s;

}
.box input[type = "username"]:focus,.box input[type = "password"]:focus{
    width: 280px;
    border-color: #2ecc71;
}
.box input[type = "submit"]{
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #2ecc71;
    padding: 14px 40px;
    width: 200px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 24px;
    transition: 0.25s;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
.box input[type = "submit"]:hover{
    background: #2ecc71;  
}
.box input[type = "button"]{
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #2ecc71;
    padding: 14px 40px;
    width: 200px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 24px;
    transition: 0.25s;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
.box input[type = "button"]:hover{
    background: #2ecc71;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `display: block` property from both of your `button` style and give width to the form of `width:450px` will make button side by side to each other, it is necassary to have form width of `450px` other wise width lesser than `450px` will make button one after another and will not make side by side.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #34495e;
}

.box {
  width: 450px;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #191919;
  text-align: center;
}

.box h1 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.box input[type="username"],
.box input[type="password"] {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #3498db;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.box input[type="username"]:focus,
.box input[type="password"]:focus {
  width: 280px;
  border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.box input[type="submit"] {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #2ecc71;
  padding: 14px 40px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #2ecc71;
}

.box input[type="button"] {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #2ecc71;
  padding: 14px 40px;
  width: 200px;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: 0.25s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box input[type="button"]:hover {
  background: #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<form class="box" action="index.html" method="post">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <input type="username" name="" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Passeword">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
    <input type="button" name="" value="Register">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you need **col-md-6** from bootstrap. Try this-

```
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
</div>
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <input type="button" name="" value="Register">
</div>
```